# Почему не обрабатывается сеттер?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

У меня есть некоторое окно, вьюМодель к ней и контрол.
Окно:

```
<myControls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="p" IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" Panel.ZIndex="500"/>
```

Когда я во вьюМодели окна изменяю IsOpen, то свойство IsOpen контрола меняется, но не обрабатывается сеттер в code-behind'е контрола.
Код свойства IsOpen в контроле:

```
        public partial class HamburgerMenu : UserControl
{
    public HamburgerMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty); }
        set
        {
            if(value != IsOpen)
                if (!IsOpen)
                    OnOpened();
                else
                    OnClosed();
            SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value);                
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(HamburgerMenu), new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

Т.е. свойство IsOpen контрола меняется, но ни один из методов(OnOpened() и OnClosed()) не вызывается, даже если убрать условные операторы. И соответственно при отладке почему-то код не проходил через сеттер.

Comment: Классическая ошибка. DependencyProperty устанавливаются напрямую, геттер и сеттер фреймворком не используются (можете удалить их и все продолжить работать), они нужны лишь для удобства программиста пишущего код. Ну и если вы откроете любой учебник по WPF, то прочтете там, что логику в сеттер помешать не нужно, она должна быть в колбеке изменения DP. А вообще в VM особого смысла использовать именно DP нету, реализуйте INPC и пишите классические свойства.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, так DP я не использую в VM, а использую в code-behind своего элемента, наследуемого от UserControl. Пробовал реализовывать INPC: просит DP.

Comment: Ага, ну в любом случае, сеттер не должен содержать логику, она должна быть в колбеке

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну все. Просто создал калбэк и написал в нем логику.

Comment: @user9039204 оформите тогда ответ, чтобы информация сохранилась.